# Mean stack | how to schedule mongodb collection action

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, cron

it's my first q here!

I'm working on Mean project

this is my collection

```
{
"created":"2019-10-7T10:57:29.579Z",
"client_name":"zuzu",
"client_phone":537486255,
"client_create":"2019-10-16T00:00:00.000Z",
"client_net_operators":"partner",
"client_package":"80gb",
"client_monthly_pay":29,
"client_balance":100,
"client_sim_number":241413244314134,
"__v":0,"_id":"5dac49d32517a19b84cb2a66"}
```

I want to make a server-side(nodejs) action
 start from client_create every monthly (2019-10-16) it's mean next `2019-11-16`

```
client_balance(100) - client_monthly_pay (29)
and update client_balace t (71)
```

I hope that I explained my-self good!

thank you
Refaat

Answer (score 0):

Try setting CRON jobs defined in your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use node module **node-schedule** for scheduling, read about that [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule)

Basically you have to schedule your job, so this is called as **cronjob**.

use it like this:

```
let schedule = require("node-schedule");

//get the date from DB, (i leave to you)
var d = new Date(date_from_DB);
var date = d.getDate();
var month = d.getMonth();
var hour = d.getHours();
var minutes = d.getMinutes();

var scheduledDateString = '* ' + minute + ' ' + hour + ' ' + day + ' ' + '* *';
/*
  let's say the date is 20 th Oct 2019, 18:10:00, then scheduledDateString will be
  '* 10 18 20 * *' which says, run this cron job (explaining from right to left) 
  any sec, 10 minutes after 6 pm, on 20th of each month, on any day.
*/

let clientCreateTimeStamp = date_from_DB.getTime();
let currentTimeStamp = new Date().getTime();
let diff = clientCreateTimeStamp - currentTimeStamp; //(assuming date_from_DB is always a future date)

//this will start cron job after diff secs, and will run on paricular date every month as explained above
var myCronJob = schedule.scheduleJob({start: diff, rule: scheduledDateString}, function(){

    // call your function from here

});
```

here, `scheduledDateString = '* ' + minute + ' ' + hour + ' ' + day + ' ' + '* *';` is a **cron-format**

The cron format consists of:

```
*    *    *    *    *    *
┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
│    │    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    │    └ day of week (0 - 7) (0 or 7 is Sun)
│    │    │    │    └───── month (1 - 12)
│    │    │    └────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│    │    └─────────────── hour (0 - 23)
│    └──────────────────── minute (0 - 59)
└───────────────────────── second (0 - 59, OPTIONAL)
```